# Angular 10 Strange Behaviour with interpolation

Tags: angular, typescript

I am struggling with some odd behaviour in Angular 10.

When the problem element is removed, everything works fine. The expected behaviour is that when the `div.passRide` is clicked on, it updates another component using the `updateViewer(passRide.id)` method which gets and displays a record.

However when I need to get some fields from `getCrewDiagram(id)` in `selector.ts`, it behaves as if every div has been clicked on and updates the viewer, showing the last thing in the list of `div`s gets displayed in `viewer`.

I have found similar questions on here but they do not address my issue, though suspect it is something basic I may well not be understanding.

selector.htm:

```
<div id="passes">
  <div class="passRide" *ngFor="let passRide of context.getPassRides();" (click)="updateViewer(passRide.id)">
    
  <p>{{ getCrewDiagram(passRide.id).header.diagNumber }}</p> <<<---- problem element here

    <table>
      <tr *ngFor="let event of passRide.events">
        <td>{{ event.activity.diagramActivity }}</td>
        <td>{{ event.noteLine ? event.note : (event.reliefLine ? event.reliefs : event.location.shortDesc) }}</td>
        <td>{{ event.activity.diagramActivity == "DEP" || event.activity.diagramActivity == "ARR" ? event.eventTime : ""}}</td>
        <td>{{ event.activity.diagramActivity == "DEP" ? event.wttid : ""}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

selector.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CrewDiagram } from '../../core/crew-diagram';
import { DiagramSetService } from '../../core/current-diagram-set.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-selector',
  templateUrl: './selector.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./selector.component.css']
})
export class SelectorComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public context: DiagramSetService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  updateViewer(index: number) : void {
    this.context.setCrewDiagram(index);
  }

  updateViewerDebug(index: number, $event): void {
    console.log($event)
    this.context.setCrewDiagram(index);
  }

  getCrewDiagram(id: number): CrewDiagram {
    return this.context.getCrewDiagram(id);
  }
}
```

diagram-set-service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CrewDiagram } from './crew-diagram';
import { CrewPuzzlePiece } from './crewPuzzlePiece/crew-puzzle-piece';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DiagramSetService {

  constructor() { }

  crewDiagrams: CrewDiagram[] // Original set from which the following are derived
  crewDiagram: CrewDiagram    // Current crew diagram (used by viewer/diagramViewer)
  filteredView: CrewDiagram[] // Diagrams on show at the moment

  passRides: CrewPuzzlePiece[] // Diagram puzzle pieces representing passing moves

  getCrewDiagrams(): CrewDiagram[] {
    return this.crewDiagrams;
  }

  getFilteredDiagrams(): CrewDiagram[] {
    return this.filteredView;
  }

  setCrewDiagrams(crewDiagrams: CrewDiagram[]) {
    this.crewDiagrams = crewDiagrams;
    this.filteredView = crewDiagrams;
  }

  getCrewDiagram(id: number): CrewDiagram{
    console.log("getCrewDiagram" + id);

    return this.crewDiagram = this.crewDiagrams.
      filter(
        function (diagram, index, array) {
          return diagram.id == id;
        }
    )[0];
  }

  setCrewDiagram(id: number): void {
    this.crewDiagram = this.getCrewDiagram(id);
    console.log("setCrewDiagram" + id);
  }

  getNumberCrewDiagrams() {
    if (!this.crewDiagrams) {
      return 0;
    }

    return this.crewDiagrams.length;
  }

  getCurrentCrewDiagram() {
    return this.crewDiagram;
  }

  filterCrewsByDepot(depotString: string): void {
    const depots = depotString.split(' ');

    this.filteredView = this.crewDiagrams.filter(function (diagram) {
      return depots.includes(diagram.header.depot);
    });
  }

  resetView(): void {
    this.filteredView = this.crewDiagrams;
  }

  setPassRides(passRides: CrewPuzzlePiece[]): void {
    this.passRides = passRides;
  }

  getPassRides(): CrewPuzzlePiece[] {
    return this.passRides;
  }
}
```

Debug output when the problem element is removed:
[image]

Debug output when the problem element is in use:
[image]

Comment: You are alterting `this.crewDiagrams` by filtering it, then overriding itself. I think you should simply `return this.crewDiagrams.filter(...)` without reassigning it to itself

Comment: Dammit! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because you are binding to a method call.

`*ngFor="let passRide of context.getPassRides();"`

and

`<p>{{ getCrewDiagram(passRide.id).header.diagNumber }}</p>`

If you'd notice, if you interact with the section, angular **ChangeDetection** will fire and angular will reconstruct the whole content again. And since you are binding your `ngFor` & `paragraph` with a method, it will essentially reconstruct the whole list again, causing `getPassRides()` & `getCrewDiagram()` to be called in a loop.

Hence, the recommended way is to construct/`map` your model,`this.crewDiagrams`, then do a property binding, essentially how you are doing for `<tr>`

```
<div id="passes">
    <div class="passRide" *ngFor="let passRide of context.getPassRides" (click)="updateViewer(passRide.id)">

        <p>{{ passRide.header.diagNumber }}</p>

        <table>
            <tr *ngFor="let event of passRide.events">
                ...
```

Comment: Cheers for the advice -- this will help speed up rendering.